# HighCharts - how to customize the tooltip for dynamically added series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Added two vertical lines with the help of addseries. Would like to customize the tooltip for these series. Please advise.

```
 this.addSeries({
                    data: [{
                        x: 4,
                        y: 110.2,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'triangle'
                        }
                    }, {
                        x: 4,
                        y: yMAx,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'triangle-down'
                        }
                    }, ],
                    showInLegend: false,
                    color: 'red',                        
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true
                    },                       
                });
```

[Here is my code's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpswt3tr/5/)

Comment: What customization you want?

Answer (score 1):

name your dynamic series and use tooltip formatter function in chart.tooltip like below code:

```
  tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
    var formatme = "";
    if(this.series.name == "first") {        
        formatme = '<span>customized</span>';
        return formatme;
    }else if(this.series.name == "second") {        
        formatme = '<span>second series</span>';
        return formatme;
    } else   return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';

}
}
```

[Demo link here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/bpswt3tr/7/)